# A team of $6$ horses be selected out of a stud of $16$,so that there shall always be $3$ out of $ABCA'B'C'$,but never $AA',BB'$ or $CC'$ together.

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can a team of $6$ horses be selected out of a stud of $16$,so that there shall always be $3$ out of $ABCA'B'C'$,but never $AA',BB'$ or $CC'$ together.

---

The number of ways of selecting $6$ horses out of $16$ is $\frac{16!}{6!10!}$ but
i do not understand the meaning of "so that there shall always be $3$ out of $ABCA'B'C'$,but never $AA',BB'$ or $CC'$ together"
The answer given in the book is $960.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably $A$, $A'$, $B$, etc. are the names of individual horses from the stud of 16. The condition states that the horse called $A$ must not be chosen along with the horse called $A'$, and similarly for $B$ and $C$.

For $ABCA'B'C'$, we make three groups: $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$. From each group, you can select at most one horse, but you must have three horses from the six given, so we must choose exactly one horse from each. This can be done in $2^3$ ways.

Once we have chosen 3 horses, we proceed to choose the remaining 3 from the other $10 = 16 - 6$ horses, which can be done in $\binom{10}{3}$ ways. So the answer is $2^3 \cdot \binom{10}{3} = 8 \cdot 120 = 960$.

Answer (score 1):

That means we can select $3$ from remaining $10$ objects ie horses so there are ${10\choose 3}=120$ wayd as $3$ from this set of a,b,c are compulsory to be selected but we can select A,A' so selecting $1$ out of $2$ we have $2$ ways same for B,B' & C,C' thus total ways of selecting $3$ from the set mentioned is $8$ . now we multiply them as both are independent sets thus total ways are $120\cdot 8=960$ .